# Crystal Reports Group in to Pages

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a Data Set which contains a around 1500 rows. The data set contains a column named JobCode. I need to sow date grouped in to Job Codes in to pages. Meaning page 1 contains jobCode1 data, page 2 containing JobCode2 data, so on.

How can I do that.

I'm using VS2010 and CR13.

Thanks in advance.

Thanushka.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but is there a reason that you can't just group by Job Code, and then set the group format to create a new page after each Group Footer?